# Build source code in Windows canning error. Illegal character

Tags: electron

Follow the electronjs.org guidelines below for building Electron itself case error :

../../electron\shell\common\extensions\api\cryptotoken_private.idl(5) : Unexpected EoF reached after

^
'canning error. Illegal character '

../../electron\shell\common\extensions\api\resources_private.idl(5) : Unexpected EoF reached after

^
'canning error. Illegal character '

how to resolve？